# cannot use a projector in ubuntu 18.04 . below is my output for xrandr

Tags: projector

[image showing the output of xrandr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdAeI.png)

the above image shows how i have tried on the issue of projecting in ubuntu 18.04 using an hp probook

Comment: Please don't add terminal text as images, cut and paste text into the question and format it properly.

Comment: What port are the projector connected to ? What errors do you see ? Is the projector registered when you connect it / turn it on ?

Comment: Perhaps that model of projector needs a specific resolution and scanning frequency which you PC is not delivering.  Please provide us with the make and model of the projector by clicking [edit] and add that vital information to the original question. Please do not use Add Comment.